# Apple rejected my app: UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key

Tags: ios, ionic3, info.plist

I developed an app with ionic 3 and I’m trying to publish it for Android and iOS. With Android the publish process was fast as a lighting bolt without any problem. With iOS the publish process is a pain, they reject my app for this reason:

"Thank you for your response.

Regarding Guideline 2.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata, we continue to find that your app does not install on iPad

To resolve this issue, it would be appropriate to check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device. Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are required and false if they must not be present on the device.

We look forward to reviewing your resubmitted app."

I checked the app info.plist but the key “UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities” is not present and I don’t know how to set it in order to address the issue.

Moreover I tested the app on several ipad simulators without any problem…

There’s anyone with the same issue ?

Comment: I forgot to say that my app is designed to work with devices that have at least ios 9 and I don't need any device hardware (gps, etc.), because the app retrive data from a rest API ad show it to the user, it's a very simple app.

Comment: Have you tested it on an iPad?

Comment: Yes, I tested the app on every simulator available in xcode 10, including ipad (older and newer version) without any problem.

Comment: It would be best to try and install a TestFlight build on an actual iPad.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any real ipad, I can test the app only on a real iphone. But the issue should be present also on the ipad simulator.

Comment: Unfortunately a simulator is not the same as a real device, and most importantly an Xcode debug build is not the same as a release build.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's impossible to have several real apple devices with different ios version...

Comment: Anyway, how this is related to the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key ?

Comment: It may not be; Apple often just gives you the most common reason that they experience a problem to help you; It may not be the actual reason in this case.  I would suggest, however, that you unzip your archived .ipa file (it is just a zip file - you can change the extension to .zip) and double check the submitted Info.plist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the "telephony" property into "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" because my app use the "tel:" link so in this case the property is required.